# Spark join is not working

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to write a spark join using to text data files. But my join doesn't working as I expect.

```
val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]", "employeedata")

val empoyees= sc.textFile("../somewhere/employee.data")


val reputations= sc.textFile("../somewhere/reputations.data")



val employeesRdd= empoyees.map(x=> (x.toString().split(",")(0), x))

val reputationsRdd= reputations.map(y=> (y.toString().split(",")(0), y))


val joineddata = employeesRdd.join(reputationsRdd).map(_._2)
```

employee.data would be like below

emp_id, firstname,lastname,age,country,Education

reputations.data would be like below

emp_id, reputation

But my results I get would be like below

(empid,first name, last name, age, country,education,,employeeid,reputation)

But I need the below output

(empid,first name, last name, age, country,education,reputation)

extra comma between employee id and the education should be removed and the employee id before the reputations should also need to be removed

Can anybody please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some **psuedo-code** (it might compile and even work if we're lucky!) to give you a bit of help:

```
// split the fields and key by id
// you could map the arrays to case classes here
val employeesRdd= empoyees.map(x=> x.toString().split(","))
    .keyBy(e => e(0))

val reputationsRdd= reputations.map(y=> y.toString().split(","))
    .keyBy(r => r(0))

val joineddata = employeesRdd.join(reputationsRdd)
    .map { case (key, (Array(emp_id, firstname,lastname,age,country,Education), Array(employee_id, reputation))) =>
        (empid,first name, last name, age, country,education,reputation)
    }
```